# Image not showing in fb share dialog

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

My website address: 
www.designyourspace.co

Image link is fine. Image is high resolution.
But the image is not showing up in the share dialog pop up.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The image is not public, you get an error when trying to load it in the browser:

> ERROR 403: FORBIDDEN

It MUST be public, Facebook needs to be able to access it.

Comment: Sorry for I am not a regular developer. I have tried some things I got through google.
Namely, changed permissions of .htaccess and the actual image file (http://www.designyourspace.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Front.jpg) to 755.
This is of no use. 
We should I do?

Comment: that would be way too broad for stackoverflow. you must have done something, files in the uploads folder are accessible by default for sure. talk to your server admin or the guy who installed wordpress.

Comment: I found the problem.
I am using a free server and the server admin says that they don't allow hotlinking of media or direct opening of url of media in free servers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok, in that case you have no chance, unfortunately. og images always must be available in public.